# Do a command in all open shells

Tags: sshfs, fuser

I use sshfs to do useful things on my dev box. I love it. But, I usually forget to `fusermount -u` before I close my lid (triggering hibernate). Then, when I come back, sshfs is frozen and I have to clean up.

I'd much rather have a script in /etc/pm/sleep.d that iterates over all my sshfs mountpoints and DWIM. I've got the `fusermount -u` code written with `df -l` checks. But, in testing, I've determined that I also need to cd out of all the mountpoints in order for `fusermount -u` to work.

But, I cannot figure out how to iterate over my open bash terminals and do useful things in them. Help?

Comment: What about unmounting lazily (`fusermount -u -z`)?

Comment: [You can remotely force a process to change its working directory.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375003/how-do-i-set-the-working-directory-of-the-parent-process/2375174#2375174) But as the author of that post says, DON'T DO IT!

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly do this by registering a custom user signal handler in `~/.bashrc`:

```
trap '[ "$PWD" = "/my/sshfs/mount" ] && cd ~' SIGUSR1
```

Then this handler will get invoked whenever you send a `SIGUSR1` signal to bash processes:

```
killall -u "$USER" -USR1 bash
```

This comes with a few caveats:

- The signal handler **must** be registered for all (interactive and non-interactive) bash instances, otherwise the default action (quit) will be taken.  I think using `~/.bashrc` will generally do this.  However, there are options to bash that will override the sourcing of this startup file.
- Any of the shell processes may be in the middle of something that relies on being in the given sshfs directory.  Randomly changing out of this directory could cause arbitrary undefined behaviour, depending on what the given script is doing at the time (or later).
- There may well be other processes started from a bash process that are still in the given directory.  There is not a whole lot that can be done for these processes, other killing them.

Comment: Setting the trap in `.bashrc` only makes it take effect in **interactive** shells. There's no reliable way to make it take effect in non-interactive shells (even if you managed to do so the script could have its own trap for USR1).

Comment: @Gilles I was wondering as much.  I don't really like this solution, but threw it out there in the hope it might get someone thinking (of something better)

Comment: That's basically what I was looking for. I'm going to have a very limited set of activities inside that mountpoint. But, outside of a regex, is there any way to determine if I'm in that directory tree (that or some child)?

Comment: @RobKinyon `df -T .` might be useful.  It shows a) the mountpoint for the current directory and b) the filesystem type.  Perhaps this will show up as `sshfs` or something similar?